# Shiny plots based on condition

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a bit perplexed on this and have been searching and reading for the better part of the morning. Have tried a few things but can't seem to get it correct.

I'm attempting to make a `shiny` plot that creates a `ggplot` based on `ui` selected inputs.

Here's an example of what I'm working with:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

subject <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E")
grp <- c(rep("One", times = 6), rep("Two", times = 8))
date <- c(rep(c("8/1/2020", "8/2/2020", "8/3/2020"), times = 4), "8/1/2020", "8/2/2020")
var <- round(rnorm(n = length(subject), mean = 0, sd = 2), 3)

df <- data.frame(subject, grp, date, var)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

I define my `ui` based on the selections I want in order: Date, Group, Subject, with the option to plot multiple subjects:

## UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput(inputId = "date",
              label = "date",
              choices = df %>% distinct(date) %>% pull(date),
              selected = min(df$date)),
  
  selectInput(inputId = "grp",
              label = "grp",
              choices = df %>% distinct(grp) %>% pull(grp),
              selected = "One"),
  
  selectizeInput(inputId = "subject",
              label = "subject",
              choices = df %>% distinct(subject) %>% pull(subject),
              multiple = T),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = "plt")
)
```

In my `server` I attempt to do two filters. The first filter is to get the date and group. the second is to then only select the subjects in the selected group. Unfortunately, `shiny` retains all subjects.

## Server

```
server <- function(input, output){
  
  output1 <- reactive({
    d <- df %>%
      filter(date == input$date,
             (grp == input$grp))
    d
  })
  
  output2 <- reactive({
    d <- output1() %>%
      filter(grp == input$grp &
               subject %in% input$subject)
    d
  })
  
  output$plt <- renderPlot({
    d <- output2()
    
    plt <- d %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = subject, y = var)) +
      geom_col()
    
    plt
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I feel like what I have above is pretty straight forward but I can't sort out why it wont return what I want. Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce a problem: the plot does reflect if there are subjects within the filtered data. It might be informative to add `browser()` to your `renderPlot` block and see what data is actually present for the plot to proceed.

Comment: Side note: `df %>% distinct(date) %>% pull(date)` can be reduced to simply `unique(df$date)`. With small data, it's about 100x faster; with larger data (~50K rows), it can be only 5-10x faster, depending on the type of data.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `unique()`. I should have been using that all along. Interesting that you cannot reproduce the problem. If you select group one from the shiny app doesn't it show you an option to select all subjects (even thoughts from group two)?

Comment: With a particular date and grp, I can choose from all (original) subjects, which may result in zero frames. But to me, that's "expected" behavior, not anomalous. ... Okay, I see what you need ... stby ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. I think you're over-`filter`ing in your two `output*` blocks. I'm inferring that `output1` should be returning just the frame that has that `date`, and then make sure that the `grp` pull-down only includes the available groups; similarly for the second pull-down into subjects. For this, I'll simplify the filtering.
2. When you know which grps and subjects are available, `updateSelectizeInput` the applicable pull-down with the available `choices`. In order to do this, we'll also add `session` to the `server` definition.

Try this:

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  selectInput(inputId = "date",
              label = "date",
              choices = df %>% distinct(date) %>% pull(date),
              selected = min(df$date)),
  
  selectInput(inputId = "grp",
              label = "grp",
              choices = df %>% distinct(grp) %>% pull(grp),
              selected = "One"),
  
  selectizeInput(inputId = "subject",
              label = "subject",
              choices = df %>% distinct(subject) %>% pull(subject),
              multiple = T),
  
  plotOutput(outputId = "plt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output1 <- reactive({
    d <- df %>%
      filter(date == input$date)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "grp", choices = unique(d$grp))
    d
  })
  
  output2 <- reactive({
    d <- req(output1()) %>%
      filter(grp == input$grp)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "subject", choices = unique(d$subject))
    d
  })
  
  output$plt <- renderPlot({
    d <- req(output2()) %>%
      filter(subject %in% input$subject)
    plt <- ggplot(d, aes(x = subject, y = var)) +
      geom_col()
    plt
  })
  
}
```

FYI: I also added calls to `req`, which prevent blocks from firing and completing when the inputs are invalid, missing, or just unstable. In smaller apps this generally doesn't happen, but if/when reactivity gets a bit big, it happens frequently enough. Even if it just happens spuriously, having `req(...)` may prevent a `renderPlot` from throwing an error temporarily/unnecessarily. (It certainly doesn't hurt anything.)

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks! I'm trying to figure out why when I select the subject though it doesn't change the figure. It keeps each subject in the respective group, regardless of which subject I select. I'm trying to sort through it now.

Comment: Brilliant! That worked really well and saved me a ton of time.